# ASP .NET C# ArgumentException invalid postback/callback - xml string as DropDownList value

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, callback, postback

I get an ArgumentException with my DropDownList ListItem value.

I have following code:

```
DropDownList ddList = new DropDownList();
ddList.DataTextField = dataTextField;
ddList.DataValueField = dataValueField;
ddList.DataSource = sqlsource;
ddList.DataBound += ddList_DataBound;
ddList.DataBind();
```

The DataValueFields contains xml strings and I get everytime the ArgumentException... so I added this:

```
 void ddList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
            item.Value = "<>\"'&\\/*+-()[]{}!?%$";
    }
```

I tried to figure out if some bad characters are involved, but with these characters everything is working fine... The problem is only happening in IE11 (I dont have IE10 or IE9) but works in Firefox. Does IE11 changes the data?

How can I encode the xml string? I tried:

```
void ddList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
            item.Value = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(item.Value)
    }
```

But it does not work either.

Update:

I tried something like:

```
void ddList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
            item.Value = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(item.Value);
    }
```

But its also not working, if I replace everything in the xml string with X it is working:

```
void ddList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList list = sender as DropDownList;
        foreach (ListItem item in list.Items)
            item.Value = Regex.Replace(item.Value, ".", "X");
    }
```

So it is not the length of the string... the xml string is well-formed, I think it is one character that IE11 does not like.

Comment: I need to see XML.  Post XML.

Comment: how do you get the ArgumentException? , on client side? what is the role of the bowser type?

Comment: Its a big xml string with 5.000 rows, I cant post it here.
I get the Exception on server side.